# Type Error calling closures stored in struct

Tags: closures, typeerror, rust

I've recently started trying to write some toy programs in rust, and I guess I wanted to take a stab at a parser combinator.
My naive attempt was this:

```
enum ParseResult<T> {
    Ok(T),
    Error (String),
}

struct Parser<'a, I,O>{
    Parse: |I|:'a ->ParseResult<O>,
}
impl<'a, I,O,J> Parser<'a, I, O>{
    fn Compose<I,O,K>(self, RHS : Parser<O,K> )->Parser<I,K>{
        Parser
        {
            Parse :  |x:I|
               {
                   let intermediate = self.Parse;
                   match intermediate(x){ //mismatched types: expected `I` but found `I` (expected type parameter but found type parameter)

                       Ok(result) =>
                       {
                           let final = RHS.Parse;
                           final(result) mismatched types: expected `O` but found `0` (expected type parameter but found type parameter)

                       }          
                      Error(result) => Error(result)
                   }
               }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure the Errors indicate something more fundamentally wrong with my approach but I'm not quite sure what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, there is a couple of errors in your program.

Currently closures are stack-"boxed", so you can't return them from functions, and that's exactly what happening in your example - you're storing a closure in `Parser` struct.

Another error is incorrect usage of generic parameters. Even without closures your method wouldn't work: `I` and `O` parameters on `Compose` method are different from those on `impl` clause, even if they share the same name.

BTW, you don't need to move a closure into `intermediate` variable. To call closures stored in fields you need to do this:

```
let intermediate = (self.Parse)(x);
```

That said, several days ago unboxed closures finally landed. With them it is possible to do what you want, though it is somewhat cumbersome at the moment.

```
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]

struct Parser<I, O> {
    parse: Box<FnMut<(I,), Result<O, String>>>
}

impl<I, O> Parser<I, O> {
    fn compose<K>(mut self, mut rhs: Parser<O, K>) -> Parser<I, K> {
        Parser {
            parse: box |&mut: x: I| {
                match self.parse.call_mut((x,)) {
                    Ok(r) => rhs.parse.call_mut((r,)),
                    Err(e) => Err(e)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This *should* work but right now it [doesn't](http://is.gd/Dh6awd), and it looks like a bug to me:

```
<anon>:11:23: 11:33 error: cannot borrow data mutably in an aliasable location
<anon>:11                 match self.parse.call_mut((x,)) {
                                ^~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:12:35: 12:44 error: cannot borrow data mutably in an aliasable location
<anon>:12                     Ok(result) => rhs.parse.call_mut((result,)),
                                            ^~~~~~~~~
```

When I rewritten this example with manually expanded unboxed closure it worked, so there's definitely some compiler problem here. Unboxed closures are very new, so such things are not unexpected. I've [submitted an issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/16668) on this.

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful, do you know where I could learn more about this? The tutorial doesn't really mention it.

Comment: @Nate, I severely doubt that there is any documentation at all. As I said, unboxed closures are *very* recent, and there are still some bugs and inconveniences; some time should pass until any proper documentation is available.

Comment: @Nate, however, I think, [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/114) and [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/105) RFCs may be of some use. The second one is temporarily closed though.